# Elevation in a View with transparent background

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a list of items with a custom background. The background is a simple shape with rounded-rect drawable filled with white color. So my view is similar to a Card. I can set an elevation on it and it works. There is a shadow beneath it.

But I want to optimize it. My window's background is white, so I thought that I can remove View's background color to reduce overdraw. But it's not that simple. As soon as I set color to transparent in my view's background drawable, elevation stops working and shadow is not drawn anymore. I've tried to use stroke instead of solid color inside my view's bakcground drawable but it doesn't work too. It's probably because of a `ViewOutline`. So I've created a custom `OutlineProvider` that returns something like this:

```
outline.drawRoundRect(0,0,view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), someRadius);
```

Now my `View` has transparent background and shadow is also visible but there is something wrong with it. It does not look good. At the top of the `View` there is some sort of a background visible beneath it. Below is a picture of my output. On the left is a view with transparent background and a custom OutlineProvider. On the right is a view with opaque white background.

[image]

Is it a bug? Or is there another way to achieve this? It seems like it's a very simple performance optimization but it turns out that it's much more complicated than it should be.

Comment: if i should ask you need an alternative or making yours work?

Comment: Post some pictures of what result you get :) also, unless you're having performance issues, it may be an idea not to optimize. It's hard to guess which parts of a program needs optimization without doing measurements, there could be other larger bottle necks that are easier to fix and it could happen that this change takes just as much power or more.

Comment: @Elltz it doesn't matter. Just want to have a card with transparent background and shadow.

Comment: @JohanShogun reducing overdraw is an important optimization especially if the view is displayed in a list. I've attached an image.

Comment: Do you have proof that this is an Optimization?  Are you having issues?  Please provide some measurements

Comment: @JohanShogun http://www.curious-creature.com/docs/android-performance-case-study-1.html but even if it would have no effect, I'm curious if it's doable or maybe it's a platform limitation.

Comment: That's a very reasonable article, and, it doesn't contradict the point I'm trying to make. If you have performance problems investigate what the problem is and fix the problem, don't do odd fixes for stuff that you don't know if it's what's making your app slow. Always always always measure and never assume. :) Assuming may cost you performance. :) looking at the picture, you may be missing some anti aliasing effect.

Comment: One thing you may want to keep in mind is that a RelativeLayout needs 2 layout passes to layout it's children, that may have an adverse effects in lists. But again, meaure ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this to be related to a known issue in Lollipop https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78248

> Thanks for the report and repro steps - this is indeed a bug, and it
>   has just been fixed in an internal branch. Will be released externally
>   in a future release.
>
> As a workaround, you can either set an alpha on the GradientDrawable,
>   or set a custom outline provider on the view casting the shadow (via
>   View#setOutlineProvider)  to query the outline from the background and
>   override the alpha provided by the drawable.
>
> The issue was that GradientDrawable was being too conservative in
>   reporting a 0 alpha in cases where it had a transparent fill. (See
>   GradientDrawable#getOutline(), for the curious)

Comment: Thanks! I've somehow missed this issue.